# How to query result order by a field encrypted in mysql

Tags: mysql

There is a table with 100K rows data as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `person_department_ref` (
  `id` bigint(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `account_department_normal` (`account`,`department_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=282 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I use Java code to encode `"account"` with `AESEncrypt`, and insert data to the table.

I can use

```
"select distinct r.account from person_department_ref r order by r.account"
```

with KEY(account_department_normal) if there is no encryption.

So how can I query the same result with with encrypted data and using KEY?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use order by to encrypted column then Mysql will give order by result on the basis of encrypted column so the data will not be match with the data of query which you mentioned. In this, you can keep both the columns in your table (account and account_encypted_value) and you can retrieve the encrypted account data on the basis of normal account order by query.

```
select distinct r.account_encypted_value from person_department_ref r order by r.account
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. But i can not keep the "account" without encrypted because of my client.